# plot a grid with arrows on it

Tags: python, plot, grid

I have a matrix like below:

[image]

First for each cell I want to find maximum neighbor. Then in a grid, plot an arrow in every cell such that the direction of arrow is to the max neighbor.

Each cell has at most 4 neighbors in directions left, right, up and down.

the output is something like this:

[image]

I have no idea how plot this in python with **matplotlib** or any other library.
here's a short block of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix = [[22, 24.4, 22, 19.4, 17.5],
          [19.8, 22, 19.8, 17.8, 16],
          [17.8, 19.8, 17.8, 16, 14.4],
          [16, 17.8, 16, 14.4, 13],
          [14.4, 16, 14.4, 13, 11.7]]

#.... after some processes
#L, R, D, U means left, right, up and down
arrows = [['R', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L']]
#plot arrows!!
```

How Plot arrows in a grid?
If `arrows[i][j] == 'R'` then plot an arrow pointed right in position [i][j] on grid, and so on.

Comment: What do you want to create?  PDF?  PNG?  SVG?  HTML?

Comment: Only a block of python code is what I need

Comment: What part of the problem is giving you trouble? Reading the data? Looping over it to decide what arrows are needed in each cell? Creating a chart at all? Putting an arrow on a chart? Please share whatever code you already have and be specific about where you're stuck.

Comment: Following up on the comment by Tim Roberts, do you need to do it specifically with matplotlib or are you free to choose any vector or raster graphics library?

Comment: You've shared the data you have and a (manual?) configuration of arrows that seems incomplete - it appears you don't know how to get started, or get any of the steps done? StackOverflow is here to help you with coding problems, but not to write your code for you. Please be clear about what your specific problem is - currently it just seems that you cannot be bothered to attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
matplotlib.pyplot.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, **kwargs)
```

Sample code:

```
arrows = {"R":(1,0), "L":(-1,0),"U":(0,1),"D":(0,-1)}
scale = 0.25

ar =     [['R', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
          ['U', 'U', 'L', 'L', 'L']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
for r, row in enumerate(ar):
    for c, cell in enumerate(row):
        plt.arrow(c, 5-r, scale*arrows[cell][0], scale*arrows[cell][1], head_width=0.1)
```

Output:
[image]