# Plotting NeedlemanWunsch - Alignment in Python: How to create GridArrows + heatmap plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alignment, needleman-wunsch

I am searching for a way to plot the Global Alignment in Python, such that it looks like in the appended image.[Global ALignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30bHG.jpg)

Despite going through many documentaries of matplotlib and seaborn, I wasn't able to find a satisfying solution.
I tried to adjust the grid lines of my plot to change them into arrows or thought of a way to implement the plt.arrow of matplotlib. However I can't think of a way to calculate the grid coordinates.

The next thing would be to color every section, such that their score is shown as heatmap.
But I am not quite sure if implementing both features would be possible?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'd use annotate  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html to make the arrows (with no text) and scatter to add the circles.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [plot a grid with arrows on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751096/plot-a-grid-with-arrows-on-it) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @JodyKlymak ! I used subplots() to make the alignment matrix and scattered the arrows and circles on it. It also worked fine for heatmapping with im = ax.imshow() :).